# changes not saved after using fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, fillna

I have several null values in a column:

```
print(df['col'].isnull().sum(axis = 0))
```

I am trying to replace them like this:

```
df['col'].fillna(value='no_val')
#df['col'].value_counts()
print(df['col'].isnull().sum(axis = 0))
```

but it doesn't work and still shows the same number of null values after using .fillna as well. If I change it like this:

```
df = df['col'].fillna(value='no_val')
```

it would start giving me a key error for 'col' in the next line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inplace=True` inside `fillna` method to reflect output

```
df['col'].fillna(value='no_val',inplace=True)
```

Or you can reassing column

```
df['col']= df['col'].fillna(value='no_val')
```

Comment: Note, they plan to deprecate inplace argument in the future, so its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
df['col'].fillna(value='no_val')
```

You don't replace your df['col'] with a null-value-filled one, you just fill null values and discard the results.

Here:

```
df = df['col'].fillna(value='no_val')
```

You reassign a single column (pd.Series object) to variable df, which means it no longer has columns.

What you should do is assign returned null-value-filled column (pd.Series) to the respective column (pd.Series) as:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].fillna(value='no_val')
```